# Omniauth-Devise Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm currently developing a Rails 3 app that uses Devise and Omniauth, and I'm trying to integrate Facebook authentication. Everything seems to be set up correctly, but when I try to go to http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook, it redirects me to Facebook where I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Missing client_id parameter."
   }
}
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong, or how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your current code, someone may help you, i can help you with php, but if you post your actual code you're using,then i may try to give you some idea on where you're going wrong or someone else might help you, without the actual code, no one can help you, because we need to analyse your code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was trying to incorporate Omniauth and Devise even though Spree Social had already been set up. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: hey dshipper, im having the same problem as you - did you completely remove Spree? and all its other components?

Comment: No i just ended up using Spree Social as far as I remember. Hope that helps!